# How can I add mouse support to my own X based window manager

Tags: c, x11, xlib, window-managers

After a lot of searching and reading docs and Q/A I could write a simple desktop environment that has a panel, and frames windows.

But now there is a problem, Where is the mouse pointer?
It doesn't even show cursor!

I wrote it in C language using Xlib, How can I add mouse to my desktop?

---

I already viewed source codes from awesomewm, tinywm, ... But I didn't understand a lot.

Comment: Window managers don't need to do anything special to show the mouse pointer, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi again! :D So where I should atach the mouse?
I'm not new to programming, I'm just new to X.